# Programmatically redirect to URL without react-router

Tags: reactjs, redirect, redux

I'm running an SPA without the help of a 3rd party router. I want to redirect to an external URL within a function.

Obviously href and installing routers do not solve my problem.

Comment: Any sample code? Coz routers are needed for routing the views.

Comment: It does not look like a redirect to me. Just a plain set window.location.href will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to redirect to an external URL and not something internal, then it's easier. You get hold of the `window.location` object and you can make it possible. I can understand why `<a href>` will not be a right choice to do it programmatically.

The below works perfectly fine. I used a `setTimeout` to simulate a programmatic redirect.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.href = 'https://praveen.science/';
    }, 1000);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @AnkitVerma Yep. It does. Thanks.